# Eclipse shortcuts confirmation prompt

Tags: eclipse, adt

I have a problem with my Eclipse environment: each time I do a shortcut (copy, paste, undo, redo, ..., any shortcut), a yellow box appears at the bottom right and prompt me to confirm the shortcut before executing it.

[image: Snapshots, uploaded after post edited]

I am on a mac and I work on ADT plugin. Anyone knows how to fix that?

Comment: I am not allowed to add an image in post but you can see a snaphot here: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/fa/14366/0/

Comment: Share snap shot here http://postimg.org/ then edit the question and add the snapshot link